# How to export data from excel chart image?

Tags: excel

I have the image of an excel chart ,but the original data is lost.Can I get the data from the chart image? through some tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't think it existed but you can try:

- [this Excel addin](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/software/chart_image_to_data/index.html)
- [digitizing](http://www.uniphiz.com/digitizing.htm), a Windows software
- [GraphClick](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16832/graphclick), a Mac OS software

Comment: +1 good advice - interesting to know these tools exist